# Code with pointers gives out 1 no matter what I tried c++

Tags: c++

So I'm doing a code which sums up all elements of field but I have to use pointers :( No matter what I tried I get 1 as output. Tried same code with multiplication but still nothing... Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

float vrat=0;
int suma (int pok2, int vel22){
    for(int z=0; z<vel22; z++){
            vrat+=pok2;
    }
    return vrat;
}

int main()
{
        /// 2. zadatak

    int vel2;
    int *vel22=&vel2;
    cout<<"Unesi broj elemenata koje hoces upisati"<<endl;
    cin>>vel2;

    int polje2[vel2];

    cout<<"Kreni unosit elemente "<<endl;
    for(int z=0; z<vel2; z++){
            cin>>polje2[z];
    }

    int *pok2=&polje2[vel2];
    suma(*pok2, *vel22);

    cout<<"Suma elemenata je "<<suma<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: The line `cout<<"Suma elemenata je "<<suma<<endl;` does not call `suma`

Comment: `int polje2[vel2];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a compile-time constant, not a runtime value such as `vel2`.  In C++, this should be `std::vector<int> polje2(vel2);`  Everything else stays the same.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm pretty sure the array he declared isn't static, so this isn't true. The array is allocated at runtime after receiving user input, otherwise the code I posted would cause a memory error. Please correct me if I'm wrong, though.

Comment: @KyleBurns solved thanks to him

Comment: @KyleBurns -- No.  Declaring arrays with a runtime expression is not valid C++.  [See this](https://rextester.com/PPWAK85180), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: @KyleBurns Variable length arrays are a compiler extension that g++ and other compilers (unfortunately) have turned on by default.  This confuses new programmers into believing that the code is valid, when it really isn't.  By setting the proper compiler switches, g++ will then not recognize that as valid code (which to me should be the default setting).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Wow. I had no idea about that! Thank you for responding:) I'll be changing the settings on my compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to do something like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

float vrat=0;
int suma (int *pok2, int vel22){
    for(int z=0; z<vel22; z++, pok2++){
            vrat+=*pok2;
    }
    return vrat;
}

int main()
{
        /// 2. zadatak

    int vel2;
    int *vel22=&vel2;
    cout<<"Unesi broj elemenata koje hoces upisati"<<endl;
    cin>>vel2;

    int polje2[vel2];

    cout<<"Kreni unosit elemente "<<endl;
    for(int z=0; z<vel2; z++){
            cin>>polje2[z];
    }

    int *pok2= polje2;
    suma(pok2, *vel22);

    cout<<"Suma elemenata je "<< vrat << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

this line

```
int *pok2=&polje2[vel2];
```

attempts to access memory outside of the bounds of polje2. Remember arrays are zero-indexed. Let me know if this isn't what you were intending to do.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! It looks like at the very end you're printing the function `suma` rather than the result. Try this instead:

```
    int result = suma(*pok2, *vel22);

    cout<<"Suma elemenata je "<< result <<endl;
```

I'm not sure why printing a function results in "1", but printing the actual result should work here.

Comment: Tried this and then it just spits out some big numbers, don't know why